# Editing existing guides I've created InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, grids, guides

I have created guides on a page with 3 columns and two rows. I am wanting to make the gutter a bit wider but I have noticed that when I go back to layout> create guides it seems that I would have to start again I can't see an option for editing existing guides.I am not sure if there is a better approach to this. I am new to grids so I am not too familiar with setting one up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Margins and Columns.. set 3 columns...

Comment: Why are you using guides for this to begin with? This is what text frame columns are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either start again, or, select the guides individually with the 'Selection Tool' and you can then edit the X an Y values to adjust these manually.